# Deploying Node/Sequelize app to heroku - Issue with PORT

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

I'm building a Node/Postgres app that I'm deploying to heroku. I'm receiving a timeout error while trying to open the app in production. According to Heroku, the error I'm receiving comes from database or port connection issues. I believe my database connection is fine, I'm getting a log that the connection was successful. Unsure if my integration with postgres caused a PORT connection issue.

Here is the error on heroku logs (not very helpful)

```
2017-07-20T17:44:53.432603+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-20T17:44:53.314516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-07-20T17:44:53.314641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
```

// app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require('morgan');
const pg= require('pg');


const index = require('./server/routes/index');
const users = require('./server/routes/users');
const rideRequests = require('./server/routes/riderequests');
const driveRequests = require('./server/routes/driverequests');
const notifications = require('./server/routes/notifications');
const trips = require('./server/routes/trips');
const email = require('./server/routes/mail');

const app = express();

pg.defaults.ssl = true;
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to postgres! Getting schemas...');

  client
    .query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;')
    .on('row', function(row) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    });
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './dist'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './dist')));

app.use(function (req,res,next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});

app.use('/email', email);
app.use('/trip', trips);
app.use('/notifications', notifications);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/ride-request', rideRequests);
app.use('/drive-request', driveRequests);
app.use('/', index);


app.use('*', index);

module.exports = app;
```

// bin/www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('atlas:server');
var http = require('http');
var models = require('../server/models');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

models.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  server.listen(port, function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    });
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
});




function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}


function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

// config/config.json

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "****",
    "password": "****",
    "database": "*_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "****",
    "password": "****",
    "database": "*_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
    "username": "****",
    "password": "****",
    "database": "*_test",
    "host": "*-*.herokuapp.com",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

All of the asterisks above contain the same sensitive information

// models/index.js

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Thanks!

**** Additional logs with successful connection to postgres upon deployment. I want to note this is not while trying to open the app, I am not receiving a anything form the server on postgres on app open.

```
2017-07-20T18:36:16.953360+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17) DeprecationWarning: PG.connect is deprecated - please see the upgrade guide at https://node-postgres.com/guides/upgrading
2017-07-20T18:36:16.991855+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to postgres! Getting schemas...
```

*****UPDATE

I believe this is a port issue. I placed a few logs in the js files and everything logs smoothly in models/index but I'm getting now logs on my www file. I believe that's where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

My problem actually had nothing to do with sequelize or my app setup. My package.json file was using app.js instead of bin/wwww for npm start. Thus app.js and models/index was getting called but not the actual server in bin/www. Anyone looking to solve this issue with an immediate crash in heroku logs, here is my suggestion. Place a few console.log()'s in your app server or app files and see what gets called. When the calling stops, that's where your issue lies.